# Constructor in dart classes

Tags: flutter, dart, class, constructor

What is difference when you use curly brackets inside constructor in dart classes and when you don't use it. And why you can not have not nullable and not initialized fields inside constructor when you use curly brackets, but you can  when you don't use curly brackets.

Here is example:

```
class Animal{
  String name;
  int age;

  Animal({this.name, this.age});
}
```

When I write class like this, there is error which says: "The parameter 'name' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.", and same for 'age'.

```
class Animal{
  String name;
  int age;

  Animal(this.name, this.age);
}
```

But when I don't use curly brackets there is no error, it allows to have null fields in constructor.

Comment: I suggest you read this article to know more about different types of constructors in dart https://betterprogramming.pub/6-types-of-constructors-in-dart-e810b6d9f354

Comment: These questions and more are answered in the Dart Language Tour on dart.dev, which we consider minimum reading before asking questions of others.  If after you've read that, you still are puzzled, we can help.

Answer (score 1):

When you use braces, you define named parameters. For example:

```
class Animal{
  String name;
  int age;

  Animal({this.name, this.age});
}
```

You should instanciate like this:

```
Animal(
  name: "Dog",
  age: 5,
);
```

If you define your constructor without braces, you defined positionnal parameters.

```
class Animal{
  String name;
  int age;

  Animal(this.name, this.age);
}
```

Then you should instantiate like this:

```
Animal("Cat", 3);
```

If you add `required` keyword, you make the parameter mandatory.

If you declare a property nullable with a `?` after type, for ewample

```
int? age
```

your name parameter become not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

with braces

```
 void main() {
  print(Animal(name: "Stark")) ; // I dont have to enter age because 
  //  its nullable
  // it is the same as 
   print(Animal(name: "Stark" , age: null))  ; // after using braces inputs not are mapped
    print(Animal(age: null)) ; // error   name: is required
  
}

  class Animal{
  String name; // not nullable
  int? age;  //  nulabble

  Animal({required this.name, this.age}); // 
}
```

so you cant map not nullable value to null because Class Null is not a subtype of String or int or any other class after null safety